# Composer won't install package dependencies

Tags: laravel, composer-php, packagist

I have created composer package, which composer.json is

```
{
    "name": "xxxx/yyyyy",
    "description": "xyz",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "xxx",
            "email": "xx@ttt.com"
        }
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "package",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^6.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "2.*",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^3.1",
        "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*",
        "yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key": "^1.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XXX\\YYY\\" : "/src"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when i install my

```
xxxx/yyyy
```

package, I need that composer install all required packages:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
    "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^6.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "2.*",
    "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^3.1",
    "venturecraft/revisionable": "1.*",
    "yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key": "^1.1"
},
```

but it dont install it.

I try composer update, composer install. Can someone help?

Project Composer.json looks like

```
{    
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",       
        "xxxx/yyyy" : "1.0.0"    
    },    
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "xxxx/yyyy",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "source": {
                    "url": "example.com",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-4" : {
                       "XXX\\YYY\\" : "/src"
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    ] 
}
```

What I can do, that Composer automatically install all package required dependencies???? Thanks for advice.

Comment: When you use "composer require xxxx/yyyy", what happen? Is there a success / error message ?

Comment: It install my package, there are no errors, but it won't install my package required dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `package` repository type. When you use this, you have to copy all information that usually resides inside the `composer.json` file of the software you are referencing.

`package` repositories are for scenarios where you are unable to add a `composer.json` file to the origin of the software. You have full control over your package, so this does not apply.

Just add a repository link of type `vcs` with the URL to the repository, and Composer will figure out the rest by looking at the `composer.json` file inside the repository. It will detect the dependencies and install them.